# Unable to import Google Vision API with Angular

Tags: angular, google-vision

I am trying to create an angular project with Google Vision, but angular refuses to compile it. Here's my app.component.ts file

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import * as vision from '@google-cloud/vision';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.scss']
})
export class AppComponent {
  title = 'Hello';
    ngOnInit() {
        const client = new vision.ImageAnnotatorClient();        
    }
}
```

And here's the error I am getting when I build the application.

```
ERROR in ./node_modules/@grpc/grpc-js/build/src/channel.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '../../package' in 'f:\temp\project\node_modules\@grpc\grpc-js\build\src'
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks in advance.

Comment: What is `@grpc`?

Comment: Its a required module for Google Vision. I am not sure what it does.

Comment: Are you using CLI?

Comment: Yes. I am using angular cli.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have `google-cloud/vision` in your package.json file? Make sure the package is installed. If you're using npm, you can just run `npm install --save @google-cloud/vision` in your project folder from the terminal to install it.

Comment: That is how I installed it originally. I have run the command again just to be sure, and google vision is on dependencies in package.json, but I still get the same error. I think the issue is with the dependencies of Google Vision's itself rather than the dependencies of the project. I could be completely wrong though, I am new to npm so I am not very familiar with it.